# How to Display Sequence Random Data like the result before on MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, random, xampp, shuffle

Hello i have tables like this :

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName 
1234        Nayeon     
1235        Jihyo     
1236        Jungyeon     
1237        Dahyun     
1238        Sana       
1239        Mina
1240        Tzuyu
1241        Chaeyeong
1241        Chaeyeong
1242        Momo
```

i used this source code :

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Employee") or die(mysql_error());

$employees = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY EmployeeID") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$position = 0;
$position2 = 0;
$toomany = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $employees )) {
    echo "<DIV>" . $toomany.substr($letters, $position, 1) . " = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . " </div>";
      $position ++;
    if($position > 25) {
        $position = 0;
        $position2 ++;
        if($position2 > 25) { echo "We need to rethink this idea."; break; }
        $toomany = substr($letters, $position2, 1);
    }
}
?>
```

to display these data :

```
 A  = Nayeon     
 B  = Jihyo     
 C  = Jungyeon     
 D  = Dahyun     
 E  = Sana       
 F  = Mina
 G  = Tzuyu
 F  = Chaeyeong
 H  = Chaeyeong
 I  = Momo
```

The problem is i want to random that data like this (from the result before):

```
C  = Jungyeon 
A  = Nayeon 
H  = Chaeyeong    
B  = Jihyo 
I  = Momo        
F  = Mina
G  = Tzuyu
E  = Sana  
F  = Chaeyeong
D  = Dahyun
```

so i add codes like this :

```
 <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Employee") or die(mysql_error());

$employees = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY EmployeeID") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$position = 0;
$position2 = 0;
$toomany = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $employees )) {
    echo "<DIV>" . $toomany.substr($letters, $position, 1) . " = " . $row['EmployeeID'] . " </div>";
      $position ++;
    if($position > 25) {
        $position = 0;
        $position2 ++;
        if($position2 > 25) { echo "We need to rethink this idea."; break; }
        $toomany = substr($letters, $position2, 1);
    }
}


function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = $positions;
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}


echo generateRandomString();

?>
```

but does not work, may you know where is the problem? Thank you

Comment: Remember that this API is deprecated and insecure (like me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomize the array you get from mysql_fetch_array.

It would look something like this:

```
$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($employees)){
    $array[] = $row
}

$i = 0;

// Assign a letter to each employee in the correct order
foreach($array as $Key => $row){
    $array[$Key]["letter"] = substr($letters, $i, 1);
    $i++;
    if($i > 25){
        $i = 0;
    }
}

// Shuffle the array
shuffle($array);

// Print each entry with correctly assigned letter and name.
foreach($array as $row) {
    echo "<DIV>" . $row["letter"] . " = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . " </div>";
}
```

Comment: sorry but i got messages like this 
`Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\random3.php on line 14` and the `EmployeeName` don't appear

Comment: Try the updated version, I did some mistakes. Sorry!

Comment: i have tried this one too but the result is like this `A = 1
B = 1
C = M
D = M
E = 1
F = 1` i dont know where the `EmployeeName` go and why they become M and 1 (LOL)

Comment: basically my problem is i want to random both the alphabeth and EmployeeName, with the same value but with a different sequence like my explanation above. Thank you for your help

Comment: oh have you edited again? i have tried the new version and it is working now but the EmployeeName changed to Alphabet too like this : `D = D
F = F
E = E
A = A
C = C
B = B` T__T

Comment: Oh really? That is very odd.. You sure that you have copied it exactly as above?

Comment: yup, i did it. i think it is like `$row['EmployeeName']` read as `$row["letter"]` how should i do for the next step? :(

Comment: Could you `var_dump($array);` just after the shuffle? Does the dump include any names, and in that case what key are they assigned to, is it "EmployeeName" ?
The weird thing is that we're not touching EmployeeName in the code i wrote above.. have you inserted any letters into the database?

Comment: i have added `var_dump($array);` after the suffle and the result is like `this array(6) { [0]=> string(4) "B234" [1]=> string(6) "Dinjun" [2]=> string(1) "E" [3]=> string(4) "A234" [4]=> string(6) "Cinjun" [5]=> string(1) "F" }
B = B
D = D
E = E
A = A
C = C
F = F`

Comment: I see, try to replace `mysql_fetch_array();` with `mysql_fetch_assoc();` :)

Comment: from `$array = mysql_fetch_array($employees);` into `$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($employees);` ? The result is like this, only 3 data appears `array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "C" [1]=> string(6) "Binjun" [2]=> string(4) "A234" }
C = C
B = B
A = A` sorry if i ask too many :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82886/discussion-between-devokansu-and-tara).